# Upgrade question was closed on Hardware Recommendations

Tags: support

Here is the link to my question:

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2497/2249

That seems straight forward enough for a [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) group.

The question was put on hold as off-topic by one guy, and he told me to go ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

My question is clearly about PC hardware.

Comment: Kinda opinion based - so not a great fit for SU either. It would depend on whether you're bottlenecking on ram or not and so on. Rescoping the question for *one* of the options might be a better idea.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - that's kind of what I'm after: How would I find the bottleneck?

Comment: I think all downvotes should require the voter to supply a comment to the poster about why that choice was made.

Comment: That's not going to happen. It's been proposed and rejected many, many times around Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Andy, does the question look like it was worded wrong or asked inappropriately? I've gotten so that I've stopped asking my questions on the whole of SO just for these nit-picking reasons.

Answer (score 2):

"One guy" was me. I closed it using the custom technical support close reason, because it was asking us to judge the technical difference between two upgrade paths.

Questions on HR are expected to ask for a recommendation of hardware, not a recommendation of a *type* of hardware. It's down to you to figure out what type of hardware you need, then you come to HR with specific requirements and ask which single piece of hardware of that type you should get that matches said requirements.

So while your question was *clearly about hardware*, that's not the only criteria for topicality.

As an aside, I didn't really intend for you to ask on Super User, but that suggestion comes with the close reason.

Comment: To me, this did not look like a question of what type of hardware. I had both types defined with manufacturer and model. My question was how to find the bottleneck in my existing setup, as Journeyman Geek phrased in his comment on my OP. The only tool at my disposal for looking at the bottleneck is Task Manager's "Performance" tab. It shows my Memory at 2.34 GB with nothing but a few Chrome browser windows open.

Comment: If Windows needs to overflow RAM into Hard Drive swap file, I don't really know how to diagnose how much of that is happening.

Comment: @jp2code "how to find the bottleneck" is even more definitely technical support.

Comment: @jp2code `My question was how to find the bottleneck...` That is what we're saying is a troubleshooting and technical support issue. It's not a problem statement looking for a specific hardware search/solution. This is a great question for Super User, but it is outside the intended use case of *this* site.

Comment: OK. It belongs on Super User. When I asked *this* question on Meta, some moderator there moved it here. Why didn't @ArtOfCode move my question on Hardware to Super User? Just lazy?

Comment: @jp2code because as it stands, it's not a good fit, as Journeyman Geek (who is a moderator there) commented on this question.